# How to set the background color of a row in FMX.Grid.TGrid?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I use an `ObjectList<Person>` and use it with the `GridGetValue()`method. My person class contains name and gender , where gender is the value. Which is invisible in the grid.

Method:

```
procedure TForm1.PersonGridGetValue(Sender: TObject; const Col, Row: Integer; var Value:TValue);
  begin
    if Col = 0 then
      Value := PersonRecord.PersonList.Items[Row].name;
  end;
```

How can I set the background color of a row based on a value from my object list?

Comment: Is it not just one cell that will be affected as Mike describes in the article? I need to get colorized a whole row. On a value which is not displayed in the table but stored in a Objectlist